# Get local profile list with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, registry

I'm on a Windows server 2008 R2 and I need an extract of the local profile list, so I use Powershell to look into the registry and get what I want :

```
$path = 'Registry::HKey_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\*'
$items = Get-ItemProperty -path $path 
Foreach ($item in $items) {
$objUser = New-Object 
System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($item.PSChildName)
$objName = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
$item.PSChildName = $objName.value
}
echo $items | Select-Object -Property PSChildName | Export-Csv 
C:\scripts\PSScripts\UserProfile.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

It worked with another machine using Windows Server 2012 R2 but here I got a lot of errors, but always the same one :

> Exception calling "Translate" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all
>   identity references could not be translated." At
>   C:\scripts\PSScripts\users_profile.ps1:5 char:34
>   +     $objName = $objUser.Translate <<<< ([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

The .csv file is created but with issues, like a profile shown more than one time, like this :

```
DOMAIN\User1
DOMAIN\User2
DOMAIN\User3
DOMAIN\User3
DOMAIN\User4
DOMAIN\User5
DOMAIN\User5
DOMAIN\User5
DOMAIN\User6
```

Is there a difference between WS2008 and WS2012 which can cause this problem? Or is it something else?

Comment: i don't have access to those OSs, so this is a different approach ... have you tried the WMI class yet? this `Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_UserProfile' -ComputerName 'LocalHost'` seems to work on win7ps5.1 quite nicely. plus, the WMI object call `Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_UserProfile' -ComputerName 'LocalHost'` has a `.Delete()` method that cleans up nearly everything.

Comment: Maybe I need to import a module or it doesn't work with WS2008, but I get this error when I try `Get-CimInstance` : _The term 'Get-CimInstance' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program._

And the other command doesn't give me the PSChildName that I need

Comment: if the CIM cmdlets are not working, then you are running an older version of PoSh. use `Get-WMIObject` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using WMI to be consistent across platforms plus some error handling:

```
$path = 'C:\scripts\PSScripts\UserProfile.csv'

Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile -Filter Special=FALSE -PipelineVariable user |
    ForEach-Object -Begin {$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'} {
        try
        {
            $id = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new($user.SID)
            $id.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Warning -Message "Failed to translate $($user.SID)! $PSItem"
        }
    } |
    Select-Object -Property @{Label='PSChildName'; Expression={$PSItem}} |
    Export-Csv -Path $path -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

---

PSv2 solution:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -Filter Special=FALSE |
    ForEach-Object -Begin {$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'} {
        try
        {
            $sid = $_.SID
            $id = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier -ArgumentList $sid
            $id.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host "Failed to translate $sid! $_" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    } |
    Select-Object -Property @{Label='PSChildName'; Expression={$_}} |
    Export-Csv -Path $path -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: The PSv2 solution actually helped me, I no longer have any duplicate in my csv file, but it still gives me some errors when I execute it : _Failed to translate S-1-5-21-2104366046-3998681915-3170305578-1235! Exception calling "Translate" with "1" argument(s):
"Some or all identity references could not be translated."_